# Add Delay to typed-react

Tags: reactjs, typed.js

I am using typed-react for using typing effect in react. I want to add delay to the typing effect. But I found that there is no such provision. Is there any alternative to make this happen?

By delay I mean starting the animation after some time.

Comment: By delay do you mean, delay the animation start, delay the string switch, or something else? Please elaborate

Comment: I'm assuming you mean react-typed, not typed-react? react-typed supports all of the typed.js config (or at least it used to; the react-typed package is pretty outdated now), and one of those options is `startDelay` (see the [typed.js docs](https://mattboldt.github.io/typed.js/docs/)).

Comment: i suppose what you are trying to achieve is called debounce - it is a common pattern in react